# MYSQL 8, Hierarchy Adjacency list, How each rows to know the top node of the alias root.?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

MYSQL 8.
Here are some rows I have in a table containing hierarchical data.

```
+-----+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------+
| id  | parent_id | sort | name                                       |
+-----+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------+
|  30 |      NULL |    1 | AKTIVA                                     |
|  40 |        30 |    2 | Aktiva Lancar                              |
|  41 |        40 |    3 | Kas & Bank                                 |
|  42 |        41 |    4 | Kas                                        |
|  43 |        41 |    5 | Kas Tunai USD                              |
|  44 |        41 |    6 | Kas Tunai Di Brankas                       |
| 213 |      NULL |   56 | HUTANG & MODAL                             |
|  88 |       213 |   57 | Hutang                                     |
|  89 |        88 |   58 | Hutang Jangka Pendek                       |
| 106 |        89 |   59 | Hutang Dagang Lainnya                      |
|  93 |        89 |   60 | Hutang SDL                                 |
|  94 |        89 |   61 | Hutang WHL                                 |
+-----+-----------+------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I use `CTE` to construct the data without much use of `SELF JOIN`
So far, here are the `query` I've used:

```
WITH RECURSIVE account_path (root, id, parent_id, name, lvl, `sort`, account_roll_up_id) AS
                   (
                       SELECT id AS root, id, parent_id, `name`, 0 lvl, `sort`, account_roll_up_id
                       FROM account_type
                       WHERE id IN (30, 213) 

                       UNION ALL

                       SELECT 30 AS root, c.id, c.parent_id, c.name, (cp.lvl + 1), c.sort, c.account_roll_up_id
                       FROM account_path AS cp
                                JOIN account_type AS c ON cp.id = c.parent_id
                   )

SELECT root, id, parent_id, CONCAT(REPEAT("  ", lvl), name) AS name, lvl, `sort`, account_roll_up_id FROM account_path
ORDER BY `sort`;
```

The results are as follows:

```
+------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
| root | id   | parent_id | name                                           | lvl  | sort | account_roll_up_id |
+------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
|   30 |   30 |      NULL | AKTIVA                                         |    0 |    1 |               NULL |
|   30 |   40 |        30 |   Aktiva Lancar                                |    1 |    2 |                  2 |
|   30 |   41 |        40 |     Kas & Bank                                 |    2 |    3 |                  2 |
|   30 |   42 |        41 |       Kas                                      |    3 |    4 |                  2 |
|   30 |   43 |        41 |       Kas Tunai USD                            |    3 |    5 |                  2 |
|   30 |   44 |        41 |       Kas Tunai Di Brankas                     |    3 |    6 |                  2 |
|  213 |  213 |      NULL | HUTANG & MODAL                                 |    0 |   56 |               NULL |
|   30 |   88 |       213 |   Hutang                                       |    1 |   57 |               NULL |
|   30 |   89 |        88 |     Hutang Jangka Pendek                       |    2 |   58 |                  9 |
|   30 |  106 |        89 |       Hutang Dagang Lainnya                    |    3 |   59 |                  9 |
|   30 |   93 |        89 |       Hutang SDL                               |    3 |   60 |                  9 |
|   30 |   94 |        89 |       Hutang WHL                               |    3 |   61 |                  9 |
+------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
```

My problem is, I need each line to know the top node of the alias `root`.
I need the following data forms.

```
+------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
| root | id   | parent_id | name                                           | lvl  | sort | account_roll_up_id |
+------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
|   30 |   30 |      NULL | AKTIVA                                         |    0 |    1 |               NULL |
|   30 |   40 |        30 |   Aktiva Lancar                                |    1 |    2 |                  2 |
|   30 |   41 |        40 |     Kas & Bank                                 |    2 |    3 |                  2 |
|   30 |   42 |        41 |       Kas                                      |    3 |    4 |                  2 |
|   30 |   43 |        41 |       Kas Tunai USD                            |    3 |    5 |                  2 |
|   30 |   44 |        41 |       Kas Tunai Di Brankas                     |    3 |    6 |                  2 |
|  213 |  213 |      NULL | HUTANG & MODAL                                 |    0 |   56 |               NULL |
|  213 |   88 |       213 |   Hutang                                       |    1 |   57 |               NULL |
|  213 |   89 |        88 |     Hutang Jangka Pendek                       |    2 |   58 |                  9 |
|  213 |  106 |        89 |       Hutang Dagang Lainnya                    |    3 |   59 |                  9 |
|  213 |   93 |        89 |       Hutang SDL                               |    3 |   60 |                  9 |
|  213 |   94 |        89 |       Hutang WHL                               |    3 |   61 |                  9 |
+------+------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------+------+--------------------+
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
SELECT 30 AS root
```

with this:

```
SELECT cp.root
```

Comment: Oke, thank you so much. Based In this question, It grows into O(N) trouble. Please see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350408/calculate-the-value-owned-by-each-node-in-the-hierarchical-database-in-mysql